# Onion Architecture in Xamarin.Forms with Autofac

Tags: autofac, xamarin.forms, onion-architecture

I want to use Onion Architecture in Xamarin.Forms.

I'm already using Autofac for Ioc. I've seen this [xDriven](https://github.com/OSTUSA/xdriven) project, but it wasnt much helpful.

This is my current solution:

[image]

Correct me if I should change something from the following:

From [SSW Rules Post here](https://rules.ssw.com.au/do-you-know-the-layers-of-the-onion-architecture), I think

- My models should go in Domain
- `IWebService` should go in Repository Interfaces
- Other processing related services should go in Business Logic Interfaces
- TestIoc Portable project will be the Client (or outermost layer)
- The implementation of the services should be outside the Onion

Now,

1. Where should my helpers go?
2. Where should my custom controls go?
3. What about all the stuff from ViewFactory?
4. What about the Ioc Module and Bootstrapper? Should they be in another project? Right now, the bootstrapper creates the Ioc container, registers the module, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind Onion architecture is to have a central application core, and every layer outside of that is an interface that can only be referenced in the direction heading to the core. So how you lay it out in your project is up to you, the idea is you only reference in one direction and the domain model only references itself, repositories are external infrastructure.

1. With your helpers. What are they helpers for? Put them in the layer that they help.
2. Custom Controls are UI layer, which is the outside layer.
3. ViewFactory looks fine as it is. IViewFactory is what anything internal references when it uses it to create a view.
4. They don't need to be in another project. Its not about the project structure, its about how the code fits together. They can be put in another project if you have other projects that contain the implementation of services you need to inject.